# How to iterate through table tr and get the value for first td? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the function where I want to get the value for first td in each table row. While looping I want to compare each of these values with the date value that user picked. After comparing the dates I need to get the position where that value should be placed in the table. Here is example of my code:

HTML Table:

```
<table id="tblBody_DBA">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="Att_5258717">
            <td>03/28/2017</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Att_5258339">
            <td>03/25/2017</td>
            <td>03/26/2017</td>
        </tr>                       
        <tr id="Att_5258337">
            <td>03/22/2017</td>
            <td>03/24/2017</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Att_5258332">
            <td>03/16/2017</td>
            <td>03/21/2017</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Att_5258331">
            <td>03/10/2017</td>
            <td>03/15/2017</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

 function sortRow(distType, rowId){
        var newVal = document.getElementById("newDate").value; //this is new value that I have to compare against existing values and return position in the table.
        var tblID = document.getElementById("parentTable").value;
        var table = window.parent.document.getElementById("tblBody_"+tblID);
        var arrayDates = [];

        for(var i=0; table.rows.length; i++){
            //Here I'm getting JavaScript error: TypeError: table.rows[i] is undefined
            alert(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
        }

    }
```

I'm getting value for each table cell in alert box but on the end error shows in my debugger. If anyone can help please let me know. I'm not able to use JQuery, plain JavaScript is the only way to et this done in my case.

Comment: What are the function parameters *distType* and *rowId* for?

Comment: Att and what ever is the id for that table row.

Comment: But you don't use those arguments?

Comment: Correct, I wasn't sure if I will need them later once I finish comparison. That can be ignored for now.

Comment: What determines where it should be placed?

Comment: Begin date is the value that should be used to determine position in the table column for specific row.

Comment: Yes but what condition that determines it?  The first value that doesn't equal?  The first value that's less than?  `I need to get the position where that value should be placed in the table` — how?  Is it going in a cell? First column? Second column? Are you replacing a value? Are you creating a new row? Is the table sorted? What tells you when to stop? Is it the first value that's not equal the selected date? Is it the first one that's greater than, is it the first one that's less than?  What happens if the dates are equal? — There's too many questions to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can just grab the first `td` from each `tr` specifically:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tblBody_DBA');
var targetTDs = table.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-child');


for (var i = 0; i < targetTDs.length; i++) {
    var td = targetTDs[i];
    console.log(td.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it but…. `let tbl = document.getElementById('tblBody_DBA'); tbl.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-child').forEach(el => console.log(el.textContent) );`

Comment: `NodeList.forEach` doesn't work in IE unfortunately https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Interesting, my guess is you could still spread it `[...NodeList].forEach(`

Comment: That DEFINITELY does not work in IE. The example code doesn't look like it's being transpiled so I just stuck with ES5

Comment: Yeah that was a joke ;) stopped caring about IE when webpack made babel easy

Comment: `[].slice.call(NodeList).forEach(` would work if you really want to use the array method!

Comment: Nah, I was using it more to drill the point of using *textContent* as opposed to *innerHTML*, but you do include some good information for people that aren't using a transpiler and want to support a full range of browsers.  For that the `c-for` loop would work, but I would cache the length variable `var i=0,n=targetTDs.length; i < n; i++` if that's even necessary (`for(var i=targetTDs.length; i--;)` would probably do).  Anyhow, my beer is wearing off.  Good convo and good points.  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

First you get all of the `tr` elements using `var allTr = document.querySelectorAll ('tr')`

Then you loop through them and get the text from the first `td`

```
for (var i = 0; i  < allTr.length; i++) {
  allTr [i].firstChild.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is in the `for` loop's end condition. You did not provide a comparison with *i* and so it was continuing beyond the last row of the table, producing the error you got.

To find the row for which the input date falls between the dates in the first and second column, you'll need to convert those values to dates and then do a comparison:

```
// Parse text as date and convert to an absolute day number 
newVal = Math.floor(Date.parse(newVal) / 24*60*60*1000);
for(var i=0; i < table.rows.length; i++){
    // Do the same conversion for the table texts
    var start = Math.floor(Date.parse(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent) / 24*60*60*1000);
    var end = Math.floor(Date.parse(table.rows[i].cells[1].textContent) / 24*60*60*1000);
    // Make the comparison
    if (start <= newVal && (newVal <= end || isNaN(end))) {
        return i; // the row where the range for that value was found
    }
}
```

Comment: Purpose of this comparison is not to find matching value. I just want to see where that value should be in my row (row position/index).

Comment: Ah, you need to find the row where the input string is interpreted as a date, and that date must be *within the range* expressed by the values in the first *and second* column of your table? If so, see my update. (Your question could have been put a bit clearer...).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table id="tblBody_DBA">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="Att_5258717">
            <td>03/28/2017</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Att_5258339">
            <td>03/25/2017</td>
            <td>03/26/2017</td>
        </tr>                       
        <tr id="Att_5258337">
            <td>03/22/2017</td>
            <td>03/24/2017</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Att_5258332">
            <td>03/16/2017</td>
            <td>03/21/2017</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Att_5258331">
            <td>03/10/2017</td>
            <td>03/15/2017</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
 function sortRow(distType){
        var table = document.getElementById(distType); //this is new value that I have to compare against existing values and return position in the table.
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
   var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0]; //first column
    console.log(firstCol.innerHTML);// or anything you want to do with first col
}
    }
 sortRow("tblBody_DBA");
 
 </script>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for error could be :

1. **document.getElementById("parentTable").value** will be returning a value which will not map to any table id when using in **window.parent.document.getElementById("tblBody_"+tblID);**
2. There are no rows in the table which has been returned by **window.parent.document.getElementById("tblBody_"+tblID);**
3. Also you havn't provided terminating condition in your for loop, which should be like : `for(var i=0; i < table.rows.length; i++)`

One more thing why you are using **window.parent** when getting the table. If your table and rest of the content are in same page then you can get table by simply calling **document.getElementById("tblBody_"+tblID);**. If you creating multi frame page then this will be required but this will get the table from the parent window of window in which you have function **sortRow** defined.

Answer (score 0):

*Forgot to paste this snippet, which might help.  Until you answer the questions on the comment, there's no way to determine the best approach.*

**Note:** The following code uses some ES6 syntax, which may not be available in IE as @Brian has pointed out.  For that reason, Babel.js or a suitable Polyfill is encouraged.

---

The idea is to grab the first-child cell of each row and iterate over them.  Using `map` you can return an array, which can then be sorted, or queried using `indexOf`.

By returning the element as the first item of the array, you can use `[0].parentNode` to retrieve the TR, or `[0].parentNode.id` to get it's ID.

```js
"use strict";
let newVal = document.getElementById('newDate').value;
console.log('newVal:', new Date(newVal));

let tbl = document.getElementById('tblBody_DBA');
var col_values = [...tbl.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-child')].map(el => {
  return [el, el.textContent, +new Date(el.textContent)];
}).sort((a,b) => a[2] > b[2] ? -1 : 1);

console.log(col_values);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>I have the function where I want to get the value for first td in each table row. While looping I want to compare each of these values with the date value that user picked. After comparing the dates I need to get the position where that value should be
  placed in the table. Here is example of my code:</p>

<p>HTML Table:</p>
<input id="newDate" value='3/24/2017' type="hidden" />
<table id="tblBody_DBA" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="Att_5258717">
      <td>03/28/2017</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Att_5258339">
      <td>03/25/2017</td>
      <td>03/26/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Att_5258337">
      <td>03/22/2017</td>
      <td>03/24/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Att_5258332">
      <td>03/16/2017</td>
      <td>03/21/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Att_5258331">
      <td>03/10/2017</td>
      <td>03/15/2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
  I'm getting value for each table cell in alert box but on the end error shows in my debugger. If anyone can help please let me know. I'm not able to use JQuery, plain JavaScript is the only way to et this done in my case.</p>
```